# Is there a way to add existing fields to a split form in Access only to the data view portion at the bottom

Tags: ms-access

I am setting up a database for some coworkers and they asked for something a little different involving forms and split forms. There are three separate people who put info into the database based on location. Due to certain reasons, the forms they use are different by a couple of factors. Those forms are being built to add data to the same table. There is a fourth person who overseas this data from the three forms and assigns priority levels to each row within the table.

The goal was to create a split form so that the fourth person can see all of the data that is being added from the three forms. Click on one of the incidents and add a priority level to each. I have that mostly done the problem is I want to add all of the data fields to the bottom half of the split form without adding more to the top half (the form). As of now I have the boxes I don't need hidden but it doesn't auto-size the form so it just looks long and takes up a ton of space.

By setting the boxes as hidden and resizing them to be smaller it kind of works but not every cell is re-sizable and it won't let me resize the form because of the extra hidden boxes.

[This is an image to help visualize what I am asking](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vZy1C.png)

Answer (score 0):

As I have understood, you want to hide/show fields corresponding to what type of records fourth person oversees.
I have solved this in form part using Tabs Control, placing different classes of fields on separate tabs. After user selects a definite record, all tabs are set to hidden, except needed.

If you want to hide this in table form appearance... This could be difficult IMHO. Better to split other way, grouping data, adding some more forms and so on.

Comment: Access is new to me, are you suggesting what I am doing is the wrong way to approach this?

Comment: It would be better if you describe problem in terms of problem, not the solution.

Comment: Try to figure out what functionality would be appropriate for customers. IMHO - there should be a standard way to do your task, as MS Access itself is an instrument for creating fast standard db applications

Comment: I have no idea what you mean, so let me see if I can rephrase my question for you. I want to have a split form that has all data in the datasheet but only has 4 boxes in the form. I want the person to be able to view the data in the datasheet, make a decision on a level and use the form up top to add to the data.

Comment: To add data where?